# Need help optimizing HQL to reduce columns returned

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an HQL below:
from ProductMain as pm join fetch pm.person as ps join fetch pm.personProduct as pp join fetch pm.personReturn as pr join fetch pp.personObjects as po where pp.id in (180,000) and ps.id >= :lowRange and ps.id <= :highRange

It seems when i query the DB i am getting every column back which is getting me a 904 error from DB... Is there any way to get specific columns back to reduce the size of the results?
Like if i have 100K results returned with 100 columns each i only want 10 columns back....
Thanks!

Comment: Is anything stopping you from using `select`, e.g. `select pm.col1, pm.col2 from ProductMain as pm ... ` ?

Comment: can i do that? so i just use the select pm.col1 , pm.col2 from ProductMain as pm join fetch pm.person as ps join fetch pm.personProduct as pp j etc?               Also, lets say there are other tables linked with ProductMain like Car, House etc and i only need a few columns from them... how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Error-904   UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY AN UNAVAILABLE RESOURCE. REASON reason-code, TYPE OF RESOURCE resource-type, AND RESOURCE NAME resource-name.... so how it related to your query that you need to find out.

Regarding fetch only required attribute **Yes,you may write like:-**

```
SELECT pm.col1, 
       pm.col2 
FROM 
from   ProductMain as pm 
JOINFETCH pm.person AS ps 
JOINFETCH pm.personproduct AS pp 
JOINFETCH pm.personreturn AS pr 
JOINFETCH pp.personobjects AS po 
WHERE pp.id IN (180,000) 
AND   ps.id >= :lowRange 
AND   ps.id <= :highRange
```

Comment: The issue i think is the table has hundred columns and when i get the results back it is overloading the resource area. So i think if i can specify a few columns i need then it will reduce the problem?

Comment: The issue i think is the table has hundred columns and when i get the results back it is overloading the resource area. So i think if i can specify a few columns i need then it will reduce the problem?                               I am assuming if the result returned if i target specific columns it can still map to the Hibernate object? What about any other table connections? If ProductMain has other links to tables with 100s of columns, how do i limit their returned columns?

Comment: So will the object returned be ProductMain objects or only a list of objects containing those rows i want? I would want to use the hibernate objects mapped as results.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles across this question like me, I found this interesting blog post on Best Practices in Hibernat: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-best-practices/

See chapter "1.2 Pojo": to answer the question in the comments section above: yes you can just select single columns and pass them into the constructor of a Pojo which could be the same entity but with another constructor.